# MiniProfiler Popup Width

Tags: internet-explorer, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm forced to use IE7 at work, and have just discovered that the MiniProfiler popup div is squashed:

[image: squashed popup]

That screenshot is from http://data.stackexchange.com, but it happens when I run the profiler on a local site too.

Anyone got any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to set the CSS overflow to visible.

I can't think of a way to change the CSS generated by the profiler without forking the code, but I can override it in the site's main CSS file:

```
div.profiler-popup
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```